# How to omit gray background color of button component in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a button like and i have some coded to change the style of button.

```
Button btnGPSFound = new Button(res.getImage("near_by_menu.png"));
btnGPSFound.getUnselectedStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
```

But there is gray box back of my button.
I don't know what the gray box is and i want to get rid of it.
can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UIID:

```
btnGPSFound.setUIID("Container");
```